# AndoridWear on going notification stop exit to home screen

Tags: android, wear-os

In AndroidWear, whenever I start an ongoing notification in my app I'm exited to the homescreen (I guess to take me to the ongoing notification?)

Is there any way around this. I want to start an ongoing notification but not immediately kick my user out of my app when I do

Here is how I create the notification:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(iFilter);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);


        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);

        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_active))
                .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.touch_to_return))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(Utilities.getBitmap(R.drawable.notification_icon_large,context))
                .setContentIntent(pIntent2)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_stop, context.getResources().getString(R.string.stop), pIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, n);
```

Comment: Can we get some code that shows how you're creating the notification?

Comment: @JessieA.Morris certainly, I have added the code